# Incorrect review: plagiarised material with added spam links

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-review

When I wanted to do a new review session, I was quite surprised by the following message:

> You reviewed https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/114581?filter-tags=qlikview incorrectly, this is plagiarised material with added spam links. Please pay more attention to each review in future
>
> Come back in 7 days to continue reviewing.

Of course, I wanted to know what I did wrong (learn for future reviews). Clicking the link leads to the following message:

[image: Approval message]

And of course the full text of the *Proposed Changes*.

Re-reading the text (since about three weeks have passed) does not directly lead to a change of my opinion. The text still seems adequate and no spam links are in the text: the only 'links' are the images, which lead to the... images.

What did I do wrong and - more importantly - how can I find out myself the next time?

Comment: The whole content was plagiarized, as stated in the ban message. And link #8 is spam.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Re-reading the text (since about three weeks have passed) does not directly lead to a change of my opinion. The text still seems adequate and no spam links are in the text: the only 'links' are the images, which lead to the... images.

You are focusing on the wrong problem. The "added spam links" was just an auxiliary issue, not the primary one. The primary problem is that the submission consisted almost entirely of plagiarized content.

Plagiarism is outright prohibited. If a submission contains plagiarized material, it is unacceptable and should be rejected. Full stop.

It doesn't matter that the text "seems adequate" after reading it. It *cannot* be adequate, since it is plagiarized.

> how can I find out myself the next time?

Pretty easy to tell here, if you are paying attention and actually reading the submission. In fact, you only had to read the first few words of the "Introduction" section. This clearly wasn't written to fit within the expected format for Documentation, and

> What is a Mapping Load Mapping Load is definitely one of...
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

is a dead giveaway of a rote copy-paste. There was a heading in the original document, which they didn't bother to remove. It didn't have any punctuation, and its formatting was stripped, so it just appears like a big, stupid, irrelevant prefix.

Another good clue is the sub-headings throughout the examples. They aren't formatted like sub-headings, again suggesting a lame copy-paste job.

Finally, it's surprisingly grammatically coherent. (Well, except for the incomplete formatting.) 99% of submissions to Documentation aren't. While that certainly isn't a bad thing, it should make you suspicious. Copying and pasting the first few lines into a Google search would return [the original site from which it was plagiarized](http://livingqlikview.com/livingqlik-roots-the-complete-guide-to-qlikview-mapping-load/)—a dead giveaway. You weren't the first person to be fooled. It looks like [this is plagiarized all over the web](https://community.qlik.com/docs/DOC-17760).

Comment: Thanks. I scanned most of the text for strange grammar/spelling/etc., but failed to see the incorrectness in the first sentence: should have seen that the title wasn't removed... Next time, for these 'almost _too_ good' proposals, I will better check for copy-paste actions.

Comment: It is a chronic problem. Being aware is the first step, @nan

Answer (score 4):

The proposal is plagiarized heavily if you see this [link](https://community.qlik.com/docs/DOC-17760).

And it was deleted altogether by another user in another review.

[Review for deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/118719?filter-tags=qlikview)

The user copied the content and images from the other community documentation of the tag.

**Edit:**

For more information about the edits/changes happened over a example click edited on bottom right corner of example.

[image]

After that you can click on view edit to see the action of each user.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the deletion reviews, those messages would already clear everything up. Is there a way I can get there myself, the next time I've made a mistake? My link only leads to my own post (which is not helpful).

Comment: I've edited my answer for your query!

Comment: Thanks! That's useful information :)